# Best way to list online users with PHP but without MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I want to make a script that will list online users when they enter a page.
Simple way is record newly entered users into MySQL and list them for example every second.
But I don't think it's a good idea with tons of users like in a facebook app come in and out of the page.
There would be a way with Flash and PHP sockets but I really don't want to use Flash either.
So is there any option left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a login sistem so you have all the info you need stored somewhere in your database!

you can use sessions!

> - http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

here there is also a solution on stackoverflow

> - [Find Number of Open Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679657/find-number-of-open-sessions)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use [Memcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) to store the users' information such as sessions for large amount of frequent query.I think it's an easy and effective way to do your job.

Comment: Memcache is workable.  Redis has some additional features that make implementation simpler, and it adds some persistence, making the data a bit more durable than memcache.  One thing we ran in to implementing this: on a high traffic site, you'll be updating and reading this data several times per second, and your dataset will probably approach a few megabytes in size. So it's pretty important to make sure that you're not using a huge datastructure stored in a single key -- instead you need to spread data over many keys, so that you aren't writing/reading megabytes for every request.