# How do I get a list of active users with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently maintain a DB table of users, when after logging in I update the table with their  ID and login_time. This works to a point but currently I can't tell if the user has been active since the login or for how long.

Is there a better way to get a complete list of users that have been active in the past X minutes?

Comment: You could add a "last seen" column in the table and refresh that every time the user makes a new request

Comment: @Pekka That'll require another DB call so I wasn't sure that was the best solution.

Comment: @Pekka웃: What about if user is logged in but did not change the page?

Comment: Making a DB request should be okay for most sites. If you have *huge* traffic, you might want to switch to a memcache at some point, but a database call shouldn't cause any performance problems  for a site with low to medium traffic. Any CMS-driven site without static caching makes dozens of them on every request

Comment: @Paul, The end of a "visit" can only be defined by an explicit logout or a timeout. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679657/find-number-of-open-sessions

Comment: Cache it, write them back to the db at a suitable interval. The data is ephemeral, so if your entire system went nipples up and that didn't get written back, no big deal.

Comment: @Tony Any suggestions for a caching method?

Comment: @Paul, PHP isn't my thing Pekka mentioned memcache, but a quick google should get you a set of options, it's a pretty standard option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get what you need would be a "Last Activity" column in the users table.  You would just update it whenever a user access a page.  Depending on what information you need it could replace the `login_time` column or it could be a new column.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to keep track of when the user made their last request in your database as a separate table or column. You can then formulate a query to select, e.g. all users that have made a request in the last 5 minutes.

PHP itself does not store - or care for - that kind of information. Unless you happen to have your own session management module which does store this kind of information, then you could use data from that.