# Show current connections

Tags: php, html, mysql

Without using user ids or logins, is there a way I can show how many people are on my site at any given time? Like a users online count thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have something like google analytics set up? If so, you can put in a widget using examples given here to do so: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/

Otherwise, doesn't look like there's an easy, out-of-the-box option. This related answer could help: [Find Number of Open Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679657/find-number-of-open-sessions?lq=1)